# Subsetting a df by sum of non-NA values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> merged%>%group_by(variable)%>%slice(5)%>%head(15)
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   variable [15]
   site_ID  variable   value 
   <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>         
   ak074   !NM03.S  NA    
   ak074   !NM05.S  NA    
   ak074   !NM091S  NA    
   ak074   !NM19N.  NA    
   ak116   ?C-5-7W. NA    
   cana157 001011   NA    
   cana157 001012   NA    
   cana157 001021   NA    
   cana157 001022   NA    
   cana157 001031   NA    
   cana157 001032   NA    
   cana157 001041   NA    
   cana157 001061   NA    
   cana157 001062   NA    
   cana157 001071   0.18
```

I want to determine how many non-NA `values` there are per `variable`, and add this sum as column to the original dataframe. I keep trying with the following code:

```
merged1 <- merged %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(k = colSums(!is.na(value)))
```

But it throws an error that:

```
Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've tried with just `sum` like this:

```
merged1 <- merged  %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(k = sum(!is.na(value)))
```

But it prints the same value throughout the column, rather than different per variable.

Comment: how many groups do you have? check the result for each group. your example only contains one group

Comment: Do you mean the variable? I've got 40,000 variables

Comment: then give an example with atleast 3 levels for the grouping variable

Comment: could you help me how to do this? each variable is repeated at least 300 times, so I'm not sure how I can show it using dput().

Comment: just slice the first 5 for example, eg `merged%>%group_by(variable)%>%slice(1:5)%>%head(20)`

Comment: now you should do the code that you posted with `sum` and check the results on your dummy dataframe

Comment: It still prints the same value for me

Comment: yes, it is supposed to print the same value for each group. You are doing a mutation. What is the problem with that?

Comment: It's supposed to print the same value per variable, not the same value for all 40,000 variables (they have different numbers of NA's). I've fixed it now anyway :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
rowsum(+(!is.na(df$value)), df$variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sum instead of colSums, since you are summing just one column.

```
merged1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(k = sum(!is.na(value)))
```

Comment: I've done this (see EDIT to the post) and it prints the same value throughout the column unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There was a conflict between the packages, and specifying dplyr worked:

```
merged1 <- kik  %>% dplyr::group_by(variable) %>% dplyr::mutate(k = sum(!is.na(value)))
```